# Remove quotes from factors of a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame that I've `discretized` using `RWeka`. RWeka's discretization creates bins with single quotes in them. Although they are not causing any problems, while plotting it looks ugly to have a variable with `'All'` category.

Here's the discretized data frame:

```
structure(list(outlook = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("sunny", "overcast", 
"rainy"), class = "factor"), temperature = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "'All'", class = "factor"), 
humidity = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "'All'", class = "factor"), 
windy = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), play = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("yes", 
"no"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("outlook", "temperature", 
"humidity", "windy", "play"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I remove the single quotes from the data and recreate the factors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df$temperature <- gsub("\\'", "", df$temperature)
df$humidity <- gsub("\\'", "", df$humidity)
> df
    outlook temperature humidity windy play
1     sunny         All      All FALSE   no
2     sunny         All      All  TRUE   no
3  overcast         All      All FALSE  yes
4     rainy         All      All FALSE  yes
5     rainy         All      All FALSE  yes
6     rainy         All      All  TRUE   no
7  overcast         All      All  TRUE  yes
8     sunny         All      All FALSE   no
9     sunny         All      All FALSE  yes
10    rainy         All      All FALSE  yes
11    sunny         All      All  TRUE  yes
12 overcast         All      All  TRUE  yes
13 overcast         All      All FALSE  yes
14    rainy         All      All  TRUE   no
```

If you need to do the same over several columns, this might be more efficient.

```
df[, 2:3] <- apply(df[, 2:3], 2, function(x) { 
    gsub("\\'", "", x)
    })
```

Comment: Is escaping the quote symbol necessary here? (I do that defensively, too...)

Comment: probably not, but it was definitely a defensive reaction on my part.

Comment: thanks @Maiasaura. `apply` solution is what I needed as I have more than 100 columns. Now, I just need to figure out which column values that have quotes in them. after looking at the values though, it looks like `gsub` is creating character vector, not a factor, but that's easy

Comment: @karlos To preserve the factor, you can simply do `levels(df$temperature) <- gsub(...)`, which will only affect the levels, not the entire structure.

Comment: I would have thought you'd have to convert to character first, or use levels as joran has specified...